# What's the preferred way of deploying a Symfony2 application?

Tags: php, deployment, symfony, frameworks

With symfony 1, there was a simple built in task for doing deployments via rsync.

```
symfony project:deploy [--go] [--rsync-dir="..."] [--rsync-options[="..."]] server
```

For larger, more complicated projects, I was in the habit of extending or overwriting that task with something more robust, but it was useful to have in there for a simple application.

My question: Is there a standard, conventional way for deploying a Symfony2 application?

There are different bundles out there that add console commands:

- https://github.com/dator/DeployBundle
- https://github.com/jfsimon/DeploymentBundle

There is also [Capifony](http://capifony.org/), which is really interesting but probably way more than I need for the simple app I'm working on.

Is there something else that I'm missing? I guess I'm surprised there isn't a simple built in command available out of the box.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't believe there is a standard, conventional way to deploy Symfony 2 applications yet, esspecially as Symfony 2 is still not at a stable release.

I highly recommened using Capifony, even for simple application deployment. It is well documented and is developed by [KnpLabs](http://www.knplabs.com/en%20KnpLabs) so is likely to be supported long term.

Comment: Fair enough, but I know there are some production applications running on Symfony2 even though it hasn't been declared stable yet. They must have settled on a deployment solution that's relatively reliable.

Comment: Why wouldn't Capifony be reliable?

Comment: Didn't mean to suggest that it wasn't. Just wondering out loud what, if any, conventions are being established the first crop of early adopters.

Comment: Quick follow up: Capifony is great! Thanks for the nudge in that direction.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to deal with ruby and you liked the `project:deploy` command from Symfony 1.4 check this bundle

- https://github.com/hpatoio/DeployBundle

You can easily install it using composer. Simply add `"hpatoio/deploy-bundle": "~1.0"` to your requirement.